# Need assistance nest for loop to add all rrows and colums in table in java

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, static, nested-loops

The question is: Reads a set of numbers given in a table, and displays the total. (add rows and columns)
Here is what I have so far. I need guidance on how to get the right output. Thanks in advance.

***Do not want to use array.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tableintegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Give the number of rows and number of columns: ");
        int rows=input.nextInt();
        int cols=input.nextInt();

        int total=0, sum=0, numbers=0;
        for(int i=0;i<rows; i++) {

            if (rows>i) { 
                System.out.print("Enter row " +(i+1)+ ":");
                numbers=input.nextInt();
                input.nextInt();
            }

            sum+=numbers;
            total=sum+numbers;
        }
        System.out.println("The grand total is: " +total);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want at the end ? Share the expected output ? sum the values, print the values ? be clear ;)

Comment: Regarding: "Reads a set of numbers given in a table" -- this sounds almost as if you may want to read in from a text file. Please clarify. Also, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd like the sum of all the rows in a given table. Say for example, user wants table to be 2 rows by 3 cols. The output will add all numbers from each row and give a grand total.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd like the user to input the rows and columns along with the numbers for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below program will ask the user to first insert the number of rows and columns separately. Next, a nested for loop is used to ask the user to insert the values for each column in each row.

The first For Loop iterates through the number of rows. For each iteration, the second For Loop will iterate through the number of columns entered. Thus asking the user to enter a value for each column.

A total of the values entered for each row will be calculated by sumOfRow. Finally, these values will be added together and a final total will be displayed.

Hope this helps :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tableintegers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of rows:");
        int rows=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of columns:");
        int cols=input.nextInt();

        int total=0, sumOfRow=0, numbers=0;
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            sumOfRow = 0;
            System.out.println("\nRow No. " + (i + 1) );
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter value for Column " + (j+1) + ": ");
                numbers = input.nextInt();
                sumOfRow += numbers;
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of Row No. " + (i+1) + " Values: " + sumOfRow);
            total += sumOfRow;
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe grand total is: " +total);

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I figured it out. I have something very similar to yours. I was not incorporating the columns into my for loop.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class tableintegers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Give the number of rows and number of columns: ");
    int rows=input.nextInt();
    int cols=input.nextInt();

    int sumRow=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=rows; i++) { 
        System.out.print("Enter row " +i+ ":"); 
            for(int j=1;j<=cols; j++) { 
                int numbers=input.nextInt();
                sumRow+=numbers;
    }
    }
        System.out.println("The grand total is: " +sumRow);
    }
}
```